# Cakephp save multiple data (users id) in a modal

Tags: php, cakephp

i want to save multiple users id in **TempUser** modal.

**Problem:**
Multiple users id is not saving in **TempUser** modal.

**First Getting all users id:**

```
$this->loadModel('User');
pr($this->User->find('all',  array('fields' => 'id')));
```

**Getting Output in Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                )
        )
)
```

Now i want to save these users id in **TempUser** modal.

```
//saving users id in **TempUser** modal
$this->loadModel('TempUser');
$this->TempUser->saveAll(); //What should i pass here in saveAll()
```

What should i do to save above data ?

Is there any inbuilt method in CAKEPHP to save this type of data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$cake = array
(
    array
        (
            'User' => array
                (
                    'id' => 1
                )
        ),

    array
        (
            'User' => array
                (
                    'id' => 2
                )
        ),

    array
        (
            'User' => array
                (
                    'id' => 3
                )
        ),
);

$tempUser = array();
foreach ($cake as $value) {
    $tempUser[]['TempUser']['id'] = $value['User']['id'];
}

$this->loadModel('TempUser'); //saving users id in **TempUser** modal
$this->TempUser->saveAll($tempUser); //What should i pass here in saveAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

saveAll expects an associative array. An example:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'User' => array(
            'name' => 'John',
            'dob' => '1987-03-04'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'User' => array(
            'name' => 'Jane',
            'dob' => '1989-06-09'
        )
    )
);

$this->User->saveAll($arr);
```